# Reading text from a file for ATM program

Tags: java

I am working my way through Cay Horstmann's book Big Java early objects, and I am having trouble with the worked example number 12.  I want to read information from a text file but the code doesn't seem to work for me.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
package javaprogrammingproject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * A text-based simulation of an automatic teller machine.
 */
public class ATMSimulator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ATM theATM;

        try {
            Bank theBank = new Bank();
            theBank.readCustomers("customers.txt");
            theATM = new ATM(theBank);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening accounts file.");
            return;
        }

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            int state = theATM.getState();

            if (state == ATM.START) {
                System.out.print("Enter customer number: ");
                int number = in.nextInt();
                theATM.setCustomerNumber(number);
            } else if (state == ATM.PIN) {
                System.out.print("Enter PIN: ");
                int pin = in.nextInt();
                theATM.selectCustomer(pin);
            } else if (state == ATM.ACCOUNT) {
                System.out.print("A=Checking, B=Savings, C=Quit: ");
                String command = in.next();

                if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                    theATM.selectAccount(ATM.CHECKING);
                } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                    theATM.selectAccount(ATM.SAVINGS);
                } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                    theATM.reset();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Illegal input!");
                }
            } else if (state == ATM.TRANSACT) {
                System.out.println("Balance=" + theATM.getBalance());
                System.out.print("A=Deposit, B=Withdrawal, C=Cancel: ");
                String command = in.next();

                if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                    System.out.print("Amount: ");
                    double amount = in.nextDouble();
                    theATM.deposit(amount);
                    theATM.Back();
                } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                    System.out.print("Amount: ");
                    double amount = in.nextDouble();
                    theATM.withdraw(amount);
                    theATM.Back();
                } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                    theATM.Back();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Illegal input!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also here is the code for the method:

```
public void readCustomers(String filename) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        int number = in.nextInt();
        int pin = in.nextInt();
        Customer c = new Customer(number, pin);
        addCustomer(c);
    }

    in.close();
}
```

And this is what is in the text file:

```
1 1234 0 1
2 2468 0 1
3 3692 2 3
4 4826 4 3
5 5050 5 6
6 6284 5 7
7 7418 5 8
8 8642 9 10
9 9876 11 12
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: "but the code doesn't seem to work for me" doesn't really help us identify the problem. What, specifically, is going wrong? Is there an error message or are you not getting the behavior you expected?

Comment: Ah yes, I get the error message "Error opening accounts file" I also didnt put the entire main method perhaps I should edit that.

Comment: Inside catch put e.printStackTrace();

Comment: Your file is in the same folder as Jar? Try putting the whole path in place of filename variable.

Comment: Putting the whole file path worked thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

In file, what are columns 3 and 4th for? when you do in.nextInt() in 2nd iteration of while loop you will get  0/1 and not 2/2468 which you are expecting to create customer object. either read file line by line or skip 2 integers to create next customer